# Koltin Flow flatMapLatest to combineTransform Using Multiple StateFlows

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-jetpack, kotlin-flow

I have the below working code which uses a dropdown to update the satusFilterFlow to allow for the filtering of characters through the getCharacterList call. The getCharacterList call uses the jetpack paging and returns Flow<PagerData<Character>>.

```
   private val statusFilterFlow =  MutableStateFlow<StatusFilter>(NoStatusFilter)
   
   // private val searchFilterFlow =  MutableStateFlow<SearchFilter>(NoSearchFilter)
   
   val listData: LiveData<PagingData<Character>> =
       statusFilterFlow.flatMapLatest{ statusFilter ->
           characterRepository.getCharacterList(null, statusFilter.status)
               .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
               .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
       }.asLiveData()
```

Given the above working solution, what is the correct flow extension to allow for me to add multiple StateFlows as I build out additional filters (e.g. SearchFilter).

I have tried combineTransorm as follows:

```
    private val statusFilterFlow =  MutableStateFlow<StatusFilter>(NoStatusFilter)

    private val searchFilterFlow =  MutableStateFlow<SearchFilter>(NoSearchFilter)

    val listData: LiveData<PagingData<Character>> =
         statusFilterFlow.combineTransform(searchFilterFlow) { statusFilter, searchFilter ->
             characterRepository.getCharacterList(searchFilter.search, statusFilter.status)
                 .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                 .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
         }.asLiveData()
```

However, this gives me a "Not enough information to infer type variable R" error.

Comment: The usual way to understand and/or fix those errors is to specify types explicitly in the function call, as in `statusFilterFlow.combineTransform<StatusFilter, SearchFilter, PagingData<Character>>(searchFilterFlow) { ... }`

Comment: This is orthogonal to the problem at hand, but I'd also suggest using the top-level `combineTransform` overload that takes all source flows as argument (instead of having the first one as receiver), so there is a better symmetry. Since I believe there is no reason one of the filters is more special than the other.

Comment: @Joffrey - awesome. I was struggling with the syntax for specifying the type explicitly. Regarding your second point - yes, using the top-level combineTransform would be better as a build out additional filters and no filter is more special than any other. Thank you!

Comment: Since this worked on its own, I made it an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual way to understand and/or fix those errors is to specify types explicitly in the function call:

```kotlin
statusFilterFlow.combineTransform<StatusFilter, SearchFilter, PagingData<Character>>(searchFilterFlow) { ... }
```

This is orthogonal to the problem at hand, but I'd also suggest using the top-level `combineTransform` overload that takes all source flows as argument (instead of having the first one as receiver), so there is a better symmetry. Since I believe there is no reason one of the filters is more special than the other.

All in all, this gives:

```kotlin
val listData: LiveData<PagingData<Character>> =
         combineTransform<StatusFilter, SearchFilter, PagingData<Character>>(statusFilterFlow, searchFilterFlow) { statusFilter, searchFilter ->
             characterRepository.getCharacterList(searchFilter.search, statusFilter.status)
                 .flowOn(Dispatchers.IO)
                 .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
         }.asLiveData()
```

Comment: While specifying the types explicitly did fix the "Not enough information" error, I'm still not getting data back. It seems that the inner flow returned from the getCharacterList method does not get invoked. Almost like nothing is collecting it. Strange. I'm still looking at it. Upvoted your answer since it was a big help.

Comment: I think the problem may lie in the `cachedIn` part. I don't know this API at all (I haven't developed on android for a while) but it might make the flow hot, which is not really how `combine` is supposed to work I guess. You might want to try moving `cachedIn` out of the combine, to just before `asLiveData()`

Answer (score 1):

For anymore else, this is too complex or doesn't work out for you ... Use Combine then flatMap latest on the top of that.

```
private val _selectionLocation: MutableStateFlow<Location?> = MutableStateFlow(null)
val searchKeyword: MutableStateFlow<String> = MutableStateFlow("")

val unassignedJobs: LiveData<List<Job>> =
    combine(_selectionLocation, searchKeyword) { location: Location?, keyword: String ->
        Log.e("HomeViewModel", "$location -- $keyword")
        location to keyword
    }.flatMapLatest { pair ->
        _repo.getJob(Status.UNASSIGNED, pair.first).map {
            Log.e("HomeViewModel", "size ${it.size}")
            it.filter { it.desc.contains(pair.second) }
        }
    }.flowOn(Dispatchers.IO).asLiveData(Dispatchers.Main)
```